# listing multiple converters during initial reading of file, possible header issue?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am reading in a CSV file to calculate some stats through Python.

I know that I can use the converters at the start of the program to adjust for some of the potential data issues, but for some reason when I try to do that, it errors with inflated results.

It's a 20-column CSV with over 1000 rows of data.
Public domain datalink is here: https://www.kaggle.com/canggih/anime-data-score-staff-synopsis-and-genre

The CSV is structured like so:

```
Title,Types,Episodes,Status,Start airing,End airing,Starting season,Broadcast time,Producers,Licensors,Studios,Sources,Genres,Duration,Rating,Score,Scored by,Members,Favorites,Description
Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood,TV,64,Finished Airing,2009-4-5,2010-7-4,Spring,Sundays at 17:00 (JST),"Aniplex,Square Enix,Mainichi Broadcasting System,Studio Moriken","Funimation,Aniplex of America",Bones,Manga,"Action,Military,Adventure,Comedy,Drama,Magic,Fantasy,Shounen",24 min. per ep.,R,9.25,719706,1176368,105387,"""In order for something to be obtained, something of equal value must be lost.""
```

My problem is when I try to run the program, it keeps telling me it can't convert ('Episodes') to a float. I know this, so I tried `skiprows=1`, removing the `header=None`, and trying to rewrite the read line as `converters = {2 : lambda s: float(s.replace('-','0'))},{2 : lambda e: float(e.replace('Episodes','0'))}` in the pd.read_csv line as well, and I still can't bypass it.

Is there a way in my `converters = {2 : lambda s: float(s.replace('-','0'))}` part of the code to list multiple converter requirements, similar to the first `.replace()` I have in there?

I am not the strongest coder in Python, but I know there is a way to fix this; I just can't see it.

My originally updated code so far:

```
#Based on: https://datatofish.com/use-pandas-to-calculate-stats-from-an-imported-csv-file/

import pandas as pd
#import statistics
import re


#I had to put in the .replace for 'Episodes', otherwise it keeps trying to convert 'Episodes' to a float value.
#Is there a better way to fix this?
df = pd.read_csv (r'dataanime.csv', encoding='utf-8', header=None, skiprows=1,
converters = {2 : lambda s: float(s.replace('Episodes','').join(s.replace('-','0')))})
df.columns = ['Title','Type','Episodes','Status','Start_airing','End_airing','Starting_season','Broadcast_time','Producers','Licensors','Studios','Sources','Genres','Duration','Rating','Score','Scored_by','Members','Favorites','Description']


# block 1 - simple stats
mean1 = df['Episodes'].mean()#Results are off
sum1 = df['Episodes'].sum()(#Results are off
max1 = df['Episodes'].max()#Results are off
min1 = df['Episodes'].min()
count1 = df['Episodes'].count()#This has the correct number of shows
median1 = df['Episodes'].median()#Looks right, maybe?
std1 = df['Episodes'].std() #Results are off
var1 = df['Episodes'].var() #Results are off

# block 2 - group by
groupby_sum1 = df.groupby(['Genres'])['Episodes'].sum()
groupby_count1 = df.groupby(['Genres'])['Episodes'].count()

#Opens the output file for the results
h_file = open("csv_stats.html","w")
#Start writing the HTML lines
h_file.write("This list shows the statistics calculated from the dataanime CSV.")
h_file.write('<br>')

# print block 1
h_file.write('Mean episodes: ' + str(mean1))
h_file.write('<br>')
h_file.write('Sum of episodes: ' + str(sum1))
h_file.write('<br>')
h_file.write('Max episodes: ' + str(max1))
h_file.write('<br>')
h_file.write('Min episodes: ' + str(min1))
h_file.write('<br>')
h_file.write('Count of shows: ' + str(count1))
h_file.write('<br>')
h_file.write('Median episodes: ' + str(median1))
h_file.write('<br>')
h_file.write('Std of episodes: ' + str(std1))
h_file.write('<br>')
h_file.write('Var of episodes: ' + str(var1))
h_file.write('<br>')

# print block 2
h_file.write('Sum of values, grouped by the Genres: ' + '<li>'+ str(groupby_sum1)+'<\li>')
h_file.write('<br>')
h_file.write('Count of values, grouped by the Genres: ' + str(groupby_count1))

h_file.close()
```

This way clears out the error message, but because `'Episodes'` is now converted to `0`, the numbers the code spits out are way off.

My results look like:
[image: Dataanime.csv calculation results]

Obviously, this is no good either. How can I set either the header to bypass the word `'Episodes'` and do the calculations, or how do I rewrite the `df = pd.read_csv (r'dataanime.csv', encoding='utf-8', header=None, skiprows=1, converters = {2 : lambda s: float(s.replace('Episodes','').join(s.replace('-','0')))})` to correct for this?

Comment: Can you share the first few rows of your input csv so we know what it looks like?

Comment: df['Episodes'] = df['Episodes'].replace({'-' : '0'}, regex=True)

Comment: Question has been updated with additional code and info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to read CSV files by letting pandas figure out how to handle the headers. By not passing anything into `header` and `skiprows`, Pandas will infer that the first line in the CSV is the header line and name your columns appropriately. To deal with the `"-"` Episode values, you can set `na_values` to indicate that `"-"` in that column is a NaN value, and use `dropna()` to remove those rows when calculating statistics.

```py
df = pd.read_csv("dataanime.csv", encoding="utf-8", na_values={"Episodes": "-"})

# calculate stats on the Episodes columns
episode_values = df["Episodes"].dropna()
mean1 = episode_values.mean()
sum1 = episode_values.sum()
...
```

Comment: For some reason, now it's giving my `'Invalid syntax'` errors when it gets to the `min1` line and beyond in the code after changing to this suggested `pd.read_csv` liine.

Comment: Try again with the edited answer? I realized I copied some code with a typo on accident

Comment: I had already fixed the bracket issue; it's still erroring at the `min1` line and beyond

Comment: @SassyG can you elaborate on what the error message looks like?

Comment: `@rchrome` it just pops up as `'Syntax Error: invalid syntax'` starting at the `min1` line. I think it might have something to do with the `-` char. It won't convert to `float` (obviously), but the `dropna()` should have fixed that...

Comment: @SassyG maybe you can share your updated code as an edit to your question so we can see what's going on here.

Comment: `@rchrome`, Just updated Q at end

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239655/discussion-between-rchome-and-sassyg).

Comment: Ok, joining chat now